# File logging in questDb docker container doesn't work

Tags: docker, logging, questdb

I have file logging enabled in the `mountedDir/conf/log.conf`:

```
# list of configured writers
writers=file,stdout

# file writer
w.file.class=io.questdb.log.LogRollingFileWriter
w.file.location=log/questdb-docker.log.${date:yyyyMMdd}
w.file.level=INFO,CRITICAL,ERROR
w.file.rollEvery=day
w.file.lifeDuration=7d

w.stdout.class=io.questdb.log.LogConsoleWriter
w.stdout.level=INFO,CRITICAL,ERROR
```

When restarting the docker container, I can see the stdout logs with `docker logs questdb` but the logfile will not be created.

Things I have tried without luck:

- Using the default file writer without the file rotation
- Using the default file path in the root directory
- Creating the log file myself and running `chmod 777` over it

Any idea what I can try to make it work?

Comment: Do you specify the root directory when starting the container? If so, do you have conf/log.conf in that directory? I've just tested your sample config and had to change the permissions on the mounted root dir, but other than that it works as expected.

Comment: @AndreiPechkurov Yeah I have mounted it correctly. Thats why the stdout configuration works. Right now I see in the stdout the error message `io.questdb.log.LogError: [2] Cannot open file for append: log/questdb-docker.log.20231113`.

Comment: Try creating the `log` sub-dir manually and then running `sudo chmod -R 777 questdb/` on your root dir.

Comment: this is working for me just fine: w.file.location=${log.dir}/log/questdb-docker.log.${date:yyyyMMdd}